# How to handle JSON response of either a list of objects or a single object using retrofit?

Tags: android, arrays, json, rest, retrofit

I am calling a REST service (not mine) using retrofit which either returns a list of objects (if there are multiple) or a single object (if one). I was able to find a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919381/retrofit-problems-handling-array-or-single-object) however the suggestion is to change the API which i don't have control of. I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456821/howto-deserialize-field-that-is-passed-either-as-a-single-object-or-as-a-list-of) thread which seems to be a good approach but is there a way to handle this using Retrofit?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611583/handle-json-response-with-multiple-type-of-the-same-name/53613811#53613811 . Please add some code, at least your "object" class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer from @pirho seems to be applicable, I found out a different and simple solution which worked for me. Hopefully it may help others as well.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(mapper))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the API response data as `Map<String, JsonElement>` in response and then parse it based on your requirement directly. As you can check here if JsonElement is JsonArray

for ex:

```
public fun parseData(val jsonElement:JsonElement){

  val gson = Gson()

  if(jsonElementFromServer.isJsonArray()){
    //here you can just parse it into some list of array

  }else{
    //here you can parse using gson to single item element or model 

  }

}
```

[JsonElement ref](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/index.html?com/google/gson/JsonElement.html)

Using Gson to get [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384064/gson-convert-from-json-to-a-typed-arraylistt) of items or single [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636254/how-to-convert-json-to-java-object-using-gson)

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the 2nd post you referred I also refer to the implementation of `PostArrayOrSingleDeserializer` described in that [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52459343/6413377).

When using Gson with Retrofit (Retrofit's converter-gson) you just need to register the adapter with custom `Gson` instance and build the `Retrofit` instance with that `Gson` instance, see below example helper class:

```
public class MyRetrofit {
    public static MyAPI getMyApi() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Object.class,
                        new ObjectArrayOrSingleDeserializer())
                .create();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
                .baseUrl("https://example.org")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);
    }
}
```

So the `Object` in the `JsonDeserializer` named `ObjectArrayOrSingleDeserializer` is the DTO you need to check for single instance or array. Replace `Object` with corresponding DTO and modify deserializer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Would happen to have a code snippet for Jackson instead of Gson?